# Iterate over each day, calculate average price of first and last 3 hours and take difference of those averages in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that looks like this,

```
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+
|      Timestamp      |    Date    |   Time   | Price |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:00:00 |    20 |
| 2017-01-01 00:01:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:01:00 |    25 |
| 2017-01-01 00:02:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:02:00 |    15 |
| 2017-01-01 00:03:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:03:00 |    20 |
| ...                 |            |          |       |
| 2017-01-01 00:20:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:20:00 |    25 |
| 2017-01-01 00:21:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:21:00 |    15 |
| 2017-01-01 00:22:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:22:00 |    10 |
| 2017-01-01 00:23:00 | 2017-01-01 | 00:23:00 |    25 |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:00:00 |    10 |
| 2017-02-01 00:01:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:01:00 |    25 |
| 2017-02-01 00:02:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:02:00 |    10 |
| 2017-02-01 00:03:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:03:00 |    25 |
| ...                 |            |          |       |
| 2017-02-01 00:20:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:20:00 |    15 |
| 2017-02-01 00:21:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:21:00 |    10 |
| 2017-02-01 00:22:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:22:00 |    25 |
| 2017-02-01 00:24:00 | 2017-02-01 | 00:23:00 |    10 |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+



Timestamp            datetime64[ns]
Date                 datetime64[ns]
Time                         object
Price                       float64
```

and I'm trying to calculate difference between the average price of the first 3 hours and the last 3 hours of a day.

Design in my mind is to do something like this;

```
For every unique date in Date
  a = avg(price.first(3))
  b = avg(price.last(3))
  dif = a - b
  append to another dataset
```

---------EDIT----------

and the expected result is;

```
+------------+---------+
|    Date    |  Diff   |
+------------+---------+
| 2017-01-01 | 3.33334 |
| 2017-01-02 |       0 |
+------------+---------+
```

My real query will be in seconds rather then hours.(I didnt wanted to put 120 rows in here show 2 minutes of the data).So hours are representations of seconds.

And there can be some missing rows in the dataset so if I just do price.first(3600) it can overshoot for some days right? If I can solve this using `df.Timestamp.datetime.hour` that will be more precise I think.

I really can't get my head around figuring how to get first and last 3 Price for everyday kind of approach. Any help will be much much appreciated!! Thank you so so much in advance!

Comment: does your dataset span multiple months/years ?

Comment: No, I created them by using ".to_datetime, format= " incase I need separately. Like where I cant use "df.Timestamp.dt.date" or "df.Timestamp.dt.hour"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you showed, the hours are ordered, so you can `groupby` day, and the get the list of the prices of the 24 hours of the day, then, you can apply a function to do the difference. You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mean    
def getavg(ls):
    mean3first=mean(ls[:3])
    mean3last=mean(ls[len(ls)-3:])
    return mean3first-mean3last


diff_means= df.groupby(['Date']).agg(list)['Price'].apply(getavg).reset_index()
diff_means.columns=['Date','Diff']
print(diff_means)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what format you want the result in, but I found a solution that I find pretty elegant:

```
unique_dates = df.Date.unique()
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for u_date in unique_dates:
    first_3 = np.mean(df[df.Date == u_date].reset_index().head(3).Price)
    last_3 =  np.mean(df[df.Date == u_date].reset_index().tail(3).Price)
    new_df = new_df.append(
        pd.DataFrame([[u_date, last_3 - first_3]], columns = ['Date', 'PriceDiff']))
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I prepared the table for expected results but I forgot to put them in the end.  Thank you very much I will try it now but can you read my edit, please

Comment: I'm thinking my solution above should still work as long as the DataFrame is sorted by TimeStamp (which it looks like it already is)! The output of my above solution is a DataFrame with one column for each unique date and another column for the price difference.

Comment: interestingly it gives the exact same results for each row and it doesn't have any logical difference from the answer above

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. See my edit. I had to write the values of last_3 and first_3 into a DataFrame at the end of each iteration.